# In Loki after signing in its taking three minutes to egt to a screen where I can actually get access to task bar apps or anything else

Tags: release-loki, desktop

After running Loki for about a week with little problem, I am getting a weird problem. I boot and the Loki boots perfectly and fast it gets me to the sign in screen I sign in with no problem, but it then takes a full three minutes to get to a workable screen, a screen where I can actually do anything its just stays with the background image and no links This happened a couple of days ago when I updated using the terminal, maybe its related to that maybe not. My machine , is an AMD 645 64 bits running a Loki 64 Bit. Audio and video works so I don't think its a card or graphic issue. Its not a black scree its the same background image as the sign in screen. after three minutes it gets to the regular desktop and it works fine from there.

Comment: You should read the last lines of file /var/log/syslog to see if you can find anything strange there. You can do it from the GUI or `tail /var/log/syslog`. Opening a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F2 (before entering your password in GUI) logging in terminal and using `top` can also help. Afterwards come back to GUI with CTRL+ALT+F7 enter your password in GUI and come back again to terminal with CTRL+ALT+F2 to see if you can determine the cause of this problem. You can alternate between GUI and terminal. NOTE: I use F2 but you can use F3, F4...

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. when I input tail /var/log/syslog I get back Nov  6 20:15:43 ronald-System gnome-session[1502]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://assets.adobedtm.com/d091b40b2c3eed7f804b1cef1ee91d7b1c7aa071/scripts/satellite-572345c264746d18b2000b7b.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
When I hit onhttp://assets.adobedtm.com/d091b40b2c3eed7f804b1cef1ee91d7b1c7aa071/scripts/satellite-572345c264746d18b2000b7b.js,

Comment: use `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to see what is causing this slow boot.
If you need  more info you can use `systemd-analyze plot >boot` , it'll create a boot.svg file inside your home folder that you can open with your browser. In that file you can see what is taking so long to boot.